# get_context("spawn") not work in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, spawn

I want to execute a function in parallel. So, I have used following codes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context

    def multi(itr):
    return {itr: [{f'test{itr}'}]}    


def test_parallel():
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    with Pool() as _pool:
         res = _pool.map(multi, list1)
```

everything is ok and works correctly.
But, when the input(list1) is increased, sometime (not always) the program gets stuck. So, I googled and found a solution that should use `get_context("spawn")`:

```
def test_parallel():
        list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        with get_context("spawn").Pool() as _pool:
             res = _pool.map(multi, list1)
```

I call the above function in python console by following commands:

```
import test_parallel
test_parallel()
```

it throws a strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/<input>'
```

But, when I remove `get_context("spawn")` and convert it to `with Pool() as _pool:` everything is ok.

OS: Ubuntu 18

Python version: 3.6

Comment: Try posting a **complete** but [minimal, reproducible program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this problem along with a stack trace. As an aside, what is the purpose of `partial(multi)` assuming this `partial` is `functools.partial`?

Comment: The post edited and partial deleted

Comment: What does "the program gets stuck" mean?

Comment: When asking question about `multiprocessing`, please *always* list the operating system you are working on, as well as the Python version you are using, since there are *significant* platform specific implementation details and they change over time.

Comment: @RolandSmith This problem has stated in this page too: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/

Comment: @Rahman There is nothing in your question to suggest that your program is using threads. Can you explain why you think that the article you linked to is relevant in this case?

Comment: @RolandSmith It is very related to my problem. In that article, the author had a problem like mine(his program get stuck/hang/freeze sometime) and he solved by using get_context("spawn"). But, when I try to use  get_context("spawn") it throws above error.

Comment: A minimal, reproducible program is one where I can copy and paste your code and run it with no modifications or additions. You have omitted, for example, necessary import statements.  Also, if you are using *spawn*, any code that creates new processes must be within an `if __name__ = '__main__':` block and I do not see that either, so I can't be sure of what you are actually executing. But moreover, if your program is raising an exception as you claim, we must know where that is occurring and you still haven't provided the stack trace for that exception.

Comment: @Rahman In the article you linked to, the problem is caused by creating multiple processes with `fork`  *in combination with* threads. If you are not using threads, you have a different problem.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you for your comment. Yes, you are right. When I call `test_parallel()` within `if __name__ = '__main__':`, it works fine. But I want  to call it from out of the script. When I call it directly from another script(like python console) it throws above error. I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: @Booboo The post edited and provided the stack trace for that exception. Also, I added import statements.

Comment: The spawn startmethod doesn't work in interactive mode.

Comment: @user2357112 what do you mean? So, I can't call `test_parallel()` function?

Comment: @user2357112 Not quite 100% correct... Spawn works fine in interactive as long as the target is from an imported module

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR; put your target function in a separate module (.py file) and import it.**

When using any other "start method" than "fork", there are some special requirements on the target function and the arguments of the child process. Specifically, they must be able to be pickled and sent via a pipe to the child process.

The `pickle` library does not copy the actual code content of functions when it serializes them, rather it copies the import path, so the function can then be imported on the other end of the pickle (this is done for classes too... The instance data is serialized, but class definition itself is re-imported).

That leads us to needing to talk about importing functions... `import` needs a file with which to execute, so if you're using an interactive console (including IPython notebooks), the main process has no file with which to import because the live session data doesn't exist anywhere but in-memory.

If you are running the script from a command prompt (or similar), functions defined in the main script can be accessed by importing the same file that was run as the main script. This is also why the main script needs to be written such that it doesn't do anything you don't want when it is imported rather than run as main via `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

There is however a workaround to using multiprocessing in an interactive environment which is to bypass the problems of importing the main script entirely, and put your target function in a separate library which is importable. That way when the child process attempts to un-pickle the target function, it has a valid file to execute.

Comment: I called it from a function that placed in separate python script. But, the error not changed. However, When I call it within `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it works fine.

Comment: @Rahman Perhaps I should have been more clear... If you are running the entire file in a non interactive mode, the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard is required, and putting the function in a separate module is not. If you are running in an interactive session, putting the function in a library will work, and there is no need for the `__name__` check.

Comment: You may need to dive into pycharm settings and adjust the way scripts are executed to make sure you know whether or not scripts are being executed in interactive mode or not. I am not familiar with that IDE, but on Spyder there are sometimes issues depending on if I "execute in existing terminal" vs "execute in external terminal"

Comment: It did not work for me. Nothing changed. I call it as a celery task.

Comment: @Rahman `celery` is a substantially different environment than standard python multiprocessing, and should have been included in your question from the beginning. At this point, you should write a new question including that.

Comment: Yes. I know it is different from standard python. But, I could not run it in standard python too.

Answer (score 0):

for linux based systems you might want to try

```
get_context("fork")
```

not spawn..